# convert a data frame with yyyymm to a date in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, data-conversion

I have a csv file where the first column consists of dates written as 199010 (October 1990).

I have to convert it to the class 'date'. I tried the following:

library(lubridate)

library(xts)

data<-read.csv("risk_free_return_monthly.csv")

dates<-data$date

data1<-as.Date(dates,format= "%Y%m")

Whenever I try to print data1 I get a list that only consits of NA

Comment: That's not a date format. You can't have a date without the day. What would be the result of parsing `199010`? `1990-10-01`? `1990-10-31`? Something in between?

Comment: I don't have a day. It's only about the year and the month!

Comment: Dates have days. The duplicate question shows how to convert such a string into a date using either zoo or lubridate, but in both cases you get back the first date of the month